# my array crashes

Tags: cocoa, exc-bad-access

I have a problem.
I have an array which is called toolsViewValues and when I'm saving, I get an
"EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and that's all... :-(

Yet, the objects inside the array are not nil.

```
NSArray *toolsViewValues = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
preferedLanguage, 
needsSwitch.isOn, 
vocSlider.value, 
exprSlider.value,
gramSlider.value, 
nil];
```

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Mike

Comment: @sudesh: Make that an answer.  But I think you mean "and not a primitive data type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make sure that everything you're putting into the array is an object. Use NSString, NSNumber and/or NSValue.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's a bit clearer to me now. I guess I'll have to read a bit more about that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `isOn` returns a boolean (judging by naming convention). Booleans cannot be put into an `NSArray`.

You'll need to wrap it in an `NSNumber` using `numberWithBool:`.

Comment: The same will hold for the slide values.

Answer (score 0):

In invite those who find it hard to understand to read the following litterature :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I hope that will help.

Thanks again.